# How to pass a querystring param to logged in page?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

we're using Liferay's auto-login and I need to pass a querystring param to the logged in page. For instance I need to be able to access the value of foo:

```
http://mysite.com/guest/group?foo=bar
```

Any idea how I could do this because obviously by default it loses the querystring during the redirect to the logged in page :(

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You will get the same from originalHttpRequest.

Please use `com.liferay.portal.util.PortalUtil` class. There are 2 methods in it. So, first, get the httpRequest by `getHttpServletRequest()` by passing `portletRequest` and then get the original http request by `getOriginalServletRequest()` by passing httpRequest that you got from `getHttpServletRequest()`.

On that request, try to search for the parameter `foo`.

Comment: Ok, im not experienced with java portal dev i assume this is  something I can do in a Liferay Hook? Could u possibly help me further with a snippet or example?

Comment: Had a good crack with hook on login.events.pre event but no luck:`http://localhost:8080/web/guest/welcome?foo=bar`
`public class LoginAction extends Action {

    public void run(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) {
     HttpServletRequest originalRequest = PortalUtil.getOriginalServletRequest(req);
  String origUrl = HttpUtil.getCompleteURL(originalRequest);
  String foo = HttpUtil.getParameter(origUrl, "foo"); 
  System.out.println("## origUrl: " + origUrl);
  System.out.println("## foo: " + foo);
    }
}`
`output: 
## origUrl: http://localhost:8080/c
## foo: `

Comment: just try creating login servie pre action hook, in the that you will get the request, try to fetch parameter from there, see if it is succesful, if you want to fetch the parameter after successful login then you have to use login post action hook

Comment: no luck as mentioned above it rerturns Null : [pastbin](http://pastebin.com/GWk9QhcM)

Answer (score 0):

You could use this code:

```
Object outcome = null;
Map<String, Object> map = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestMap();
if (map != null) {
  for (String key : map.keySet()) {
    if (map.get(key) instanceof HttpServletRequestWrapper) {
      HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) ((HttpServletRequestWrapper) map.get(key)).getRequest();
      outcome = request.getParameter("foo");
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

I have it in my bean constructor.